# Following schema creation throwing errors

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lat REAL,
    lon REAL,
    user TEXT,
    uid INTEGER,
    version INTEGER,
    changeset INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT
);                       # this worked

CREATE TABLE nodes_tags (
    id INTEGER,
    key TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    type TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES nodes(id)
);                      # this did not work

CREATE TABLE ways (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    user TEXT,
    uid INTEGER,
    version TEXT,
    changeset INTEGER,
    timestamp TEXT
);                      # this worked

CREATE TABLE ways_tags (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    key TEXT NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    type TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ways(id)
);                      # this did not work

CREATE TABLE ways_nodes (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    node_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    position INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ways(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (node_id) REFERENCES nodes(id)
);                      # this did not work
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '     value TEXT,     type TEXT,     FOREIGN KEY
>   (id) REFERENCES nodes(id) )' at line 3

comma not valid input at this position

Comment: Do you really need TEXT? if you use InnoDB as table engine the TEXT columns are stored separated from the other columns meaning you need to use one extra random i/o on memory (innodb_buffer_pool) or disk (which is slow) to get the TEXT column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-K). You should really avoid using it as a Table/Column Name. Consider naming it to something else; otherwise you will have to use backticks around it.

```
CREATE TABLE nodes_tags (
    id INTEGER,
    `key` TEXT,  -- I'd prefer renaming it. eg: node_key
    value TEXT,
    type TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES nodes(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ways_tags (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `key` TEXT NOT NULL,  -- I'd prefer renaming it. eg: ways_tags_key
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    type TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ways(id)
);
```

Comment: ThankYou so much. _/\_  MVP

Comment: @Rex I am not sure what `_/_` means. Hopefully something good. Anyways, please rename the column to something else instead. Also, if you look at the reference link given in the answer; you can find more reserved keywords there and avoid them in future.

Comment: oh it was the _ / \ _ (hands together to say thanks) sign :) 

Yes . will do that